# How to group all values by semicolon separated in SQL query

Tags: sql-server

Please help how to achieve data as per shown in attached image

Highlighted rows actually group on Item Number field

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: I didn't see comma instead semicolon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following should work:

```
SELECT distinct ItemNumber,SUBSTRING(
(SELECT ';' + TotalItem+' x '+ItemName
FROM YourTable
where ItemNumber=c.ItemNumber
ORDER BY ItemNumber
FOR XML PATH('')),2,200000 ) AS NewDescription from YourTable c
GO
```

Comment: Thanks for prompt help, Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```
SELECT 
      it.[Item Number]
    , Values1 = STUFF(CAST((
        SELECT [text()] = ', ' +  CAST(it2.TotalItem AS varchar)    + ' x ' + it2.ItemName
        FROM dbo.Items it2
        WHERE it2.[Item Number] = it.[Item Number]
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE) AS VARCHAR(100)), 1, 2, '')

FROM ( 
    SELECT DISTINCT [Item Number]
    FROM dbo.Items
) it
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use **[`STRING_AGG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql)**

```
SELECT [Item Number],  STRING_AGG (CONCAT(TotalItem,'x',ItemName), ';') as tags 
FROM dbo.TableName
GROUP BY [Item Number];
```

Comment: Just wondering that, is this function available in SQL 2008 or 2012 or 2016?

Comment: I'm don't have running environment by which I can confirm, but as per documentation `starting with 2017`

Comment: Thanks a lot for prompt help. Cheers mate

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  t2.ItemNumber ,
        STUFF(( SELECT  ',' + CAST(TotalItem AS VARCHAR) + ' x ' + ItemName
                FROM    @MyTable t1
                WHERE   t1.ItemNumber = t2.ItemNumber
              FOR
                XML PATH('')
              ), 1, 1, '') AS NewDescription
FROM    @MyTable t2
GROUP BY t2.ItemNumber
```

[DEMO](http://rextester.com/TBNY78673)